# How to create a DataTable and filling it with a data from the database using the DataView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I want to create a table programmatically using `HtmlTable` or `DataTable` and then filling this table with the data from the database using `DataView`.

I could be able to create a table using `HtmlTable` but when I did a search regarding "how to fill `HtmlTable` with a data using `DataView`", I found that DataView will not work with `HtmlTable`. So I repeated creating the table using the `DataTable`, but now I need to fill it with the data using `DataView`, so how can I do that?

My code:

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Name");
    DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Username");

    col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

    table.Columns.Add(col1);
    table.Columns.Add(col2);

    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row[col1] = "John";
    row[col2] = "John123";
    table.Rows.Add(row);


    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = table;
    gv.DataBind();
```

Regarding the table in the database, the schema of the User Table is:

```
Username, FirstName, LastName, Age, Job
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set the `DataSource` property of a `GridView` to be the `DataView`.

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = yourDataView;
gv.DataBind();
```

By the way, I don't see the need to instantiate the GridView programmatically; you probably can define it on your markup directly. But that's for you to decide what suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could so something like:

```
var MyTable = new DataAccess.MyTable();
MyTable.LoadAll();
row[col1] = MyTable.Username;
row[col2] = MyTable.FirstName + MyTable.LastName;
row[col3] = MyTable.Age;
row[col4] = MyTable.Job;
```

Hope this helps.